# UIView animation: simulating velocity

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I am trying to use a `UIView` animation to simply move a view onto the screen:

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:.10 delay:0 options: nil animations:^
   {
       self.menusView.frame = endingMenuViewFrame;;
   }
    completion:^(BOOL finished)
   {

   }];
```

I'm wanting to add an animation so that UIView floats a little when it reaches the top before it comes down, i.e. akin to if someone jumps in the air - when they first jump, they shoot up quickly, but then gravity gradually slows them down as they reach the top of their jump, and eventually it pushes them back to earth. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code. This will make your view bounce three times with each time your height reduced by half. You may add more bounces.

```
CGFloat offset = 200.0;

CGRect originalFrame = self.menusView.frame;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    CGRect frame = self.runnerAlertView.frame;
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - offset;
    self.menusView.frame = frame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

        self.menusView.frame = originalFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            CGRect frame = self.menusView.frame;
            frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - 0.5 *offset;
            self.menusView.frame = frame;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

                self.menusView.frame = originalFrame;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                    CGRect frame = self.runnerAlertView.frame;
                    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - 0.25 * offset;
                    self.menusView.frame = frame;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

                        self.menusView.frame = originalFrame;
                    }];
            }];
        }];
        }];
    }];
}];
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for that. It sort of does it, I was playing around with nesting UIViewAnimations the same way you did and it never quite does get it right. I wonder if I might need to use core animation instead.